# How do I disable Burstly's console logging?

Tags: ios, logging, burstly

How do I disable Burstly's (excessively) spammy console logging on iOS?  Seeing as devices only store the previous X lines of logs, and burstly fills about 80% of that, I can't always get the logs I added for other things myself.  Since all I get for the burstly lib is a binary, I can't strip out the logging statements myself, and I haven't seen anything in the documentation about a flag I could pass in either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[BurstlyAdUtils setLogLevel:BurstlyLogLevelNone];

Comment: Having a colleague check this first, will mark as accepted as soon as we've verified it.  Thanks.

Comment: It works fine. Thanks! By the way, these are the logging levels that you can use: `typedef enum {
 AS_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG = 0,
 AS_LOG_LEVEL_INFO = 1,
 AS_LOG_LEVEL_WARN = 2,
 AS_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR = 3,
 AS_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL = 4
} AS_LogLevel`. I went with `AS_LOG_LEVEL_ERROR`. Not sure if the default one is 'debug' or 'info'.